# what libraries a program use during its compilation (Installation)

Tags: qemu

I want to know about static libraries and dynamic libraries that a program use when it is going to install on a system.
Basically I want to install qemu on my Linux system. I want to know what libs it use during configure and make ( compilation and running)

Comment: Just try configure it first, you will be notified when library isn't available. Basically, you need to install make, autoconf, libtool, pixman, libglib, etc.

Comment: Brother I want to install qemu on other system ( a debian server) where it gives bugs. so my instructor ask me to find what libs it used when installed on my laptop ( I first install it on my own system where it work).

Comment: what kind of error did you get?

Comment: you can see on this link. Answer given here is also not going to help.   http://askubuntu.com/questions/418969/bugs-in-compiling-qemu

Comment: have you tried the suggested answer on the link you provided? (running apt-get build-dep qemu). to install libglib, try "sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev"

Comment: yes i try but it is not going to work.

Comment: Please provide the error message by clicking edit on your question.

Comment: just inform me how to know libraries used by a program at time of compilation (Make, configure)

Comment: You can't. There's no such "tool", you may try to look into README if they provide it, this is also why you need to run "configure" before running make, configure script will check library dependencies for you before you run make. Just see inside configure script if you don't find the information in the README. Good luck.

Comment: How can i do cross compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ldd` to list shared libraries needed by an executable. I don't have qemu installed at my system, but here is an example for ifconfig:

```
 $ ldd /sbin/ifconfig
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff50ffe000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb960021000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb96040e000)
```

From here you can search the package containing files with the `apt-file` command:

```
$ apt-file search ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc6: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Make sure you install the packages listed.

(FYI: `ldd` will also tell you which libraries are missing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There's no such "tool", you may try to look into `README` if they provide it, this is also why you need to run "`./configure`" before running `make`, the configure script will check library dependencies for you before you run `make`. Just see inside configure script if you don't find the information in the README. Good luck.